# Error using custom hook inside a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
 let { photos, isQuering, empty, error } = useFetch(brand, isOld);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOld) {
      const { photos: photosTest } = useFetch(brand, isOld);
      photos = photosTest;
    }
  }, [isOld]);
```

useFetch is a custom hook that I have and I want to bring the old photos when the isOld state is true, the code above useEffect is called normally and the photos load, but I run into the error that useFetch is not being called inside the body a function component, the following error appears "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:", that is, I am doing something very wrong that I cannot to see! If you can help me, I would appreciate it very much!

Editing because of Danko! The Hook!

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useScrollPagination } from './flow-manager';
import { db } from '../../Firebase';
import { userContext } from '../appContext';

export default function fetch(brand, isOld) {
  const {
    userData: { uid },
  } = useContext(userContext);

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [lastDoc, setLastDoc] = useState(undefined);
  const [isQuering, setIsQuering] = useState(false);
  const [empty, setEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);
  const shouldFetchMore = useScrollPagination();
  const [shouldKeepFecthing, setShouldKeepFetching] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isQuering || finished) return;
    if (!lastDoc || shouldFetchMore || shouldKeepFecthing) {
      setIsQuering(true);
      let query = !isOld
        ? db
            .collection('catalog-images')
            .where('brandName', '==', brand)
            .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
            .endBefore(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 40))
            .limit(20)
        : db
            .collection('catalog-images')
            .where('brandName', '==', brand)
            .where('photoPeriod', '==', 'Antiga')
            .limit(20);

      if (lastDoc) query = query.startAfter(lastDoc);

      query
        .get()
        .then(snap => {
          const newPhotos = [];
          let valid = 0;
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            const { url, pricetag, timestamp } = doc.data();
            if (!uid && pricetag === 'Sim') return;
            brand && newPhotos.push({ url, timestamp });
            valid += 1;
          });
          setPhotos(oldPhotos => [...oldPhotos, ...newPhotos]);
          setShouldKeepFetching(valid < 10);
          setEmpty(snap.empty);
          setLastDoc(snap.docs[snap.docs.length - 1]);
          setFinished(snap.docs.length < 20);
          setIsQuering(false);
        })
        .catch(setError);
    }
  }, [!!lastDoc, shouldFetchMore, shouldKeepFecthing, isQuering]);
  return { photos, isQuering, empty, error, fetch };
}
```

**Last Update:**
Here, where I am calling the hook:

```
let {
    photos,
    isQuering,
    empty,
    error,
    useFetch: refetch,
  } = useFetch(brand, isOld);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOld) {
      let { photos: photosTest } = refetch(brand, isOld);
      photos = photosTest;
      setIsOld(false);
    }
  }, [isOld]);
```

Aaaand, the hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useScrollPagination } from './flow-manager';
import { db } from '../../Firebase';
import { userContext } from '../appContext';

export default function useFetch(brand, isOld) {
  const {
    userData: { uid },
  } = useContext(userContext);

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [lastDoc, setLastDoc] = useState(undefined);
  const [isQuering, setIsQuering] = useState(false);
  const [empty, setEmpty] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);
  const shouldFetchMore = useScrollPagination();
  const [shouldKeepFecthing, setShouldKeepFetching] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isQuering || finished) return;
    if (!lastDoc || shouldFetchMore || shouldKeepFecthing) {
      setIsQuering(true);
      let query = !isOld
        ? db
            .collection('catalog-images')
            .where('brandName', '==', brand)
            .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
            .endBefore(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 40))
            .limit(20)
        : db
            .collection('catalog-images')
            .where('brandName', '==', brand)
            .where('photoPeriod', '==', 'Antiga')
            .limit(20);

      if (lastDoc) query = query.startAfter(lastDoc);

      query
        .get()
        .then(snap => {
          const newPhotos = [];
          let valid = 0;
          snap.forEach(doc => {
            const { url, pricetag, timestamp } = doc.data();
            if (!uid && pricetag === 'Sim') return;
            brand && newPhotos.push({ url, timestamp });
            valid += 1;
          });
          setPhotos(oldPhotos => [...oldPhotos, ...newPhotos]);
          setShouldKeepFetching(valid < 10);
          setEmpty(snap.empty);
          setLastDoc(snap.docs[snap.docs.length - 1]);
          setFinished(snap.docs.length < 20);
          setIsQuering(false);
        })
        .catch(setError);
    }
  }, [!!lastDoc, shouldFetchMore, shouldKeepFecthing, isQuering]);
  return { photos, isQuering, empty, error, useFetch };
}
```

Comment: `!!lastDoc` is not a dependency for useEffect. It should be `lastDoc`

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest something else:

1. update your `useFetch` so it will have `refetch` function end add it to returned object.
2. now, your updated hook can be destructured like this: `const { photos, isQuering, empty, error, refetch } = useFetch(brand);`
3. your useEfect can be used like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isOld) {
      refetch();
      setIsOld(false)
    }
  }, [isOld]);
```

#### Update:

You must rename your custon hook to start with `use`. Otherwise there is no way for react to differ it from other functions. So, instead of naming it `fetch` rename it to `useFetch`.

Comment: Hi Danko!
Just try your solution and I'am still getting the error:
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: Can you update your post and share the code for `useFetch` hook? It might be that you have error there. Btw does error message shows in which file and component you have error?

Comment: Danko, just updated with the hook!
Being new to all of this world of hooks, so I'am really struggling :/
And the error come like this:
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14746)
    at useContext (react.development.js?72d0:1493)
    at fetch (useFetch.js?e08e:6)
    at eval (index.js?66bc:146)

Comment: Have updated my answer. Let me know if you are making progress

Comment: Still getting the break rules of hooks error, I will update with the actual code, just a second!

Comment: Have you seen how I suggest useEffect to be used? Don't do this:  `let { photos: photosTest } = refetch(brand, isOld);  photos = photosTest; ...`

Comment: Also you are doing this in destructuring: `useFetch: refetch,` refetch shoud not be the same thing as useFetch. If you do that than you are having hook inside useEffect. That is  forbiden because of [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you can't call a hook from another hooks. Hooks are only called from component body (top-level). Your code makes no sense on a few levels:

```
let { photos, isQuering, empty, error } = useFetch(brand, isOld);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isOld) {
    const { photos: photosTest } = useFetch(brand, isOld); // can't call a hook here
    photos = photosTest; // can't mutate component-level variables
  }
}, [isOld]);
```

Comment: So, something like this?


  function fetch() {
    const { photos, isQuering, empty, error } = useFetch(
      brand,
      isOld,
    );
    return { photos, isQuering, empty, error };
  }

  
  const { photos, isQuering, empty, error } = fetch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOld) {
      fetch();
    }
  }, [isOld]);